# R scraping Rvest get text

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scrpaing this url and in'targetes' i want to get the name of the away players from this url http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/tercera-divisio-nacional/grup-v/aa/vilafranca-fc-a/aa/igualada-cf-a

In this case I want to get these names:

[image]

I try to use xpath method to get this:

```
url<-paste0("http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/tercera-divisio-nacional/grup-v/aa/vilafranca-fc-a/aa/igualada-cf-a")

web_partit<-read_html(url)

type_card_local_player <- web_partit %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div') %>% html_attr('class')
local_player <- web_partit %>% html_nodes('#acta-header+ .p-0_ml .acta-table~ .acta-table+ .acta-table a') %>% html_text()

type_card_away_player <- web_partit %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/div') %>% html_attr('class')
away_player <- web_partit %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a') %>% html_text()
```

and css selector method:

```
away_player <- web_partit %>% html_nodes('.p-0_ml+ .p-0_ml .acta-table2+ .acta-table a') %>% html_text()
```

And in the two cases i get empty results

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your code has some errors in it (e.g., is `hml_nodes` really `html_nodes`? that's not the only one). Also, it is incomplete, what code do you start with? It helps when your question is self-contained and reproducible, and it's difficult to troubleshoot when your code is syntactically incorrect from the start. While it's likely that this is just a copy/paste mistake, it is frustrating differentiating between those errors and actual errors underneath (that you don't know are wrong).

Comment: @r2evans i updated  my code on the question

Comment: Good start. What is `hml_nodes(.p-0_ml+ .p-0_ml .acta-table2+ .acta-table a)`? That's not valid R code (or there is a lot you are not sharing). First is the function name. Second, are there quote marks anywhere to indicate a string?

Comment: @r2evans updated on the ask

Comment: (Is it safe to assume that `**away_player**` is you trying to emphasize a variable name `away_player`? If so, please don't. Code in a code block should be executable as-is, with no editing for markdown or missing quotes or things like that.)

Comment: @r2evans updated on the ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a technique that helps you find the right table (among two) and gets you on the next step. There is still some data-cleaning that you'll likely need to do.

```r
web_partit %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  Filter(function(a) grepl("Targetes", a), .) %>%
  html_table()
# [[1]]
#                                 Targetes                 Targetes Targetes
# 1   16\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRIBEIRO FONSECA, LUCAS   RIBEIRO FONSECA, LUCAS      17'
# 2    4\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFONTANILS LLACH, DAVID   FONTANILS LLACH, DAVID      34'
# 3 17\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDE LA TORRE PEREZ, ANGEL DE LA TORRE PEREZ, ANGEL      75'
# 4  12\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBOADA CASANELLAS, ORIOL  BOADA CASANELLAS, ORIOL      80'
# [[2]]
#                                            Targetes                Targetes Targetes
# 1 13\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBOSCH SOLÃ<U+0089>, PAU BOSCH SOLÃ<U+0089>, PAU      70'
# 2               5\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBARALDES ESCUDE, DAVID  BARALDES ESCUDE, DAVID      74'
# 3              22\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tGARCIA GONZALEZ, OSCAR  GARCIA GONZALEZ, OSCAR      89'
```

(I'm not an `rvest` guru, so perhaps somebody will have a more efficient way.)

You can see all tables on a page with:

```r
html_nodes(web_partit, "table")
# {xml_nodeset (16)}
#  [1] <table class="d-n d-b_impr" style="width:100%;margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:-200px;"><tr>\n<td class="w-33 tc">\n    ...
#  [2] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="3">Titulars</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n ...
#  [3] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="3">Suplents</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n ...
#  [4] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="2">Equip Tècnic</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<t ...
#  [5] <table class="acta-table2">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="4">Substitucions</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n ...
#  [6] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="3">Targetes</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n ...
#  [7] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="2">Àrbitres</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n ...
#  [8] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="4">Gols</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody><tr>\n<td cl ...
#  [9] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr class="th">\n<th class="tc uppercase">Estadi</th>\n                           ...
# [10] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr class="th">\n<th class="tc uppercase">Comparativa</th>\n                      ...
# [11] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="3">Titulars</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n ...
# [12] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="3">Suplents</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n ...
# [13] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="2">Equip TÃ¨cnic</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n< ...
# [14] <table class="acta-table2">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="4">Substitucions</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n ...
# [15] <table class="acta-table">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan="3">Targetes</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n ...
# [16] <table class="d-n d-b_impr" style="position:relative;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;width:100%;"><tr>\n<td class="w-33 tc"> ...
```

and when we `grepl` it, there is an implied `as.character`, on that node, which greps for a pattern within

```r
as.character(html_nodes(web_partit, "table")[[15]])
# [1] "<table class=\"acta-table\">\n<thead><tr>\n<th colspan=\"3\">Targetes</th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class=\"white oswald tc p-r z-0 w-44px\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"num-samarreta-acta2\">13</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"samarreta-acta2\">\n<span class=\"p-a faf-base\" style=\"color:#000;\"></span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"p-a faf-base shirt-border\" style=\"color:transparent;\"></span><td><a href=\"http://fcf.cat/jugador/1920/futbol-11/tercera-divisio-nacional/grup-v/35060669/37589706\">BOSCH SOLÃ<U+0089>, PAU</a></td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class=\"p-0 tr\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-stats\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-stat-box\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"groga-s\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-minut-targeta\">70'</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n<tr>\n<td class=\"white oswald tc p-r z-0 w-44px\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"num-samarreta-acta2\">5</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"samarreta-acta2\">\n<span class=\"p-a faf-base\" style=\"color:#0884FF;\"></span><td><a href=\"http://fcf.cat/jugador/1920/futbol-11/tercera-divisio-nacional/grup-v/35060669/649805\">BARALDES ESCUDE, DAVID</a></td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class=\"p-0 tr\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-stats\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-stat-box\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"groga-s\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-minut-targeta\">74'</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n<tr>\n<td class=\"white oswald tc p-r z-0 w-44px\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"num-samarreta-acta2\">22</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"samarreta-acta2\">\n<span class=\"p-a faf-base\" style=\"color:#0884FF;\"></span><td><a href=\"http://fcf.cat/jugador/1920/futbol-11/tercera-divisio-nacional/grup-v/35060669/647599\">GARCIA GONZALEZ, OSCAR</a></td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class=\"p-0 tr\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-stats\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-stat-box\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"groga-s\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"acta-minut-targeta\">89'</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>"
```

---

You can do a little more cleaning with this. I don't know that this is robust to any other nuances (for instance if fewer or more columns are pulled), but it does clean things up a bit:

```r
library(dplyr)
web_partit %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  Filter(function(a) grepl("Targetes", a), .) %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[2]] %>%         # you need to find a way to "know" this definitively
  as_tibble(., .name_repair = "unique") %>%
  mutate(
    num = gsub("^([0-9]+).*", "\\1", Targetes...1),
    Targetes...1 = gsub("^[0-9]+\\s*", "", Targetes...1)
  )
# New names:
# * Targetes -> Targetes...1
# * Targetes -> Targetes...2
# * Targetes -> Targetes...3
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Targetes...1             Targetes...2             Targetes...3 num  
#   <chr>                    <chr>                    <chr>        <chr>
# 1 "BOSCH SOLÃ\u0089, PAU"  "BOSCH SOLÃ\u0089, PAU"  70'          13   
# 2 "BARALDES ESCUDE, DAVID" "BARALDES ESCUDE, DAVID" 74'          5    
# 3 "GARCIA GONZALEZ, OSCAR" "GARCIA GONZALEZ, OSCAR" 89'          22
```